# Outputing the value constantly when inside a do while loop

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while, cs50

Please see my code below. It's not overly long or complicated.

In short the problem I am having is that my do while loop is supposed to check if the values of input or input1 are positive and if they are not *then* print the message onto the terminal.

However, it is always printing this message onto the terminal, even if I enter positive float values for input and input1.

Thanks for the assistance,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float input = get_float("How much money did you pay?");
    float input1 = get_float("What was the total value of the goods?");

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive *number* : ");
    }
    while ((input || input1) < 0.0);


    int answer = round(input - input1);
    {
        printf("Your total change is %i: ", answer);
    }
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `while ((input || input1) < 0.0)` isn't what you want.  C is not English.  The expression `input || input1` evaluates to `0` or `1` depending on the truth values of `input` and `input1`.  It will never be less than zero, so your loop will always exit after the first pass.  You probably want `while (input < 0.0 || input1 < 0.0)`.

Comment: WiCLL, Detail: Given "check if the values of input or input1 are positive", do you consider 0.0 _positive_? Do you consider -0.0 _positive_?

Comment: ...moreover, you should update (read again) input and input1, after having said "please enter positive number"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues:

1. the condition `(input || input1) < 0.0` is wrong it should be `(input < 0.0 || input1 < 0.0)`
2. your while loop contains only a printf, so it is normal that it may loop forever, because once you enter the loop, `input` and `input1` never change.

You want for example this (includes omitted):

```
int main(void)
{
    float input;
    float input1;

    do
    {
      input = get_float("How much money did you pay?");
      input1 = get_float("What was the total value of the goods?");

      if (input < 0.0 || input1 < 0.0)
      {
        printf("Please enter positive numbers.\n");
        continue;   // restart the loop
      }
    }
    while (0);
    
    int answer = round(input - input1);
    {
        printf("Your total change is %i: ", answer);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

**Bonus:** `input` and `input1` is very poor naming. Why not call these variables `MoneyPaied` and `ValueOfGoods`? Right: in this simple program it doesn't matter much, but as soon as your programs get a bit more complex it matters, because your code will be easier to understand (including for yourself).

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing multiple conditions in c, write them separately. You can write your conditions in while loop as following:
You should also take inout inside the loop.
do
{
printf("Please enter a positive *number* : ");
float input = get_float("How much money did you pay?");
float input1 = get_float("What was the total value of the goods?");
}
while ((input < 0.0 || input1 <0.0);

Now, your code will work fine.

Here's an explaination of why your code was not working. Every non-zero float or integer in C evaluates to `True` or 1. `(input || input1)` will evaluate to to 0 or 1 but it can never be less than `0.0`. Therefore, your condition is always False. It breaks the loop and prints this message onto the terminal.

Comment: There are more problems in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the do-while loop

```
do
{
    printf("Please enter a positive *number* : ");
}
while ((input || input1) < 0.0);
```

then the statement

```
    printf("Please enter a positive *number* : ");
```

is always executed independent on the condition used in the loop. So using the do-while loop does not make a sense.

Also the condition of the loop is always evaluates to false because the expression `(input || input1)` can be equal to `1` when one of operands, input or input1 is not equal to 0, or can be equal to 0 otherwise. But in any case the result, 1 or 0, can not be less than 0.0.

What you need is the following

```
float input;
float input1;

do
{
    input  = get_float("How much money did you pay? ");
    input1 = get_float("What was the total value of the goods? ");

    if ( input < 0.0f || input1 < 0.0f )
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive *number* : ");
    }
} while ( !( input < 0.0f || input1 < 0.0f ) );
```

Or it will be better to split the loop into two loops. For example

```
float input;
float input1;

do
{
    input  = get_float("How much money did you pay? ");
    if ( !( 0.0f < input ) )
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive *number* : ");
    }
} while ( !( 0.0f < input ) );

do
{
    input1 = get_float("\nWhat was the total value of the goods? ");
    if ( !( 0.0f < input1 ) )
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive *number* : ");
    }
} while ( !( 0.0f < input1 ) );
```

Also enclosing unconditionally statements in these compound statements

```
{
    printf("Your total change is %i: ", answer);
}
{
    printf("\n");
}
```

does not make a sense. You could just write

```
int answer = round(input - input1);

printf("Your total change is %i: ", answer);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `input;  = ... ` (?!)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks. It was a typo.